# Can I run VSCODE in a text-only Linux terminal window similar to the way I run VIM?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on a linux machine my work can benefit from VSCODE.

When I install and try to run VSCODE on an Ubuntu machine, I get this error:

```
root@ca012294dcc1:/tmp# code --user-data-dir /tmp
To use Visual Studio Code with the Windows Subsystem for Linux, please install Visual Studio Code in Windows and uninstall the Linux version in WSL. You can then use the `code` command in a WSL terminal just as you would in a normal command prompt.
Do you want to continue anyway? [y/N] y
To no longer see this prompt, start Visual Studio Code with the environment variable DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL defined.

/usr/share/code/bin/../code: error while loading shared libraries: libxshmfence.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

- WSL is out of scope. This is not a WSL senario
- Remote SSH is out of scope. I know I can connect over SSH with Visual Studio Code. But I like to replace something like VIM with code
- There is no Linux GUI available. Only text mode.

Is what I am trying to do possible?